# Find Minimum value in class hierarchy

Tags: c#

Given the following classes (lets pretend they are populated), how would you find the minimum value of any `val` for an instance of `test1`?

```
    public class test1
    {
        public int val;
        public List<test2> Tests;
    }

    public class test2
    {
        public int val;
        public List<test3> Tests;
    }

    public class test3
    {
        public int val;
        public List<test4> Tests;
    }

    public class test4
    {
        public int val;
    }
```

Comment: You only have 1 test1.  What's there to search?  Did you mean for any instance of any test class?  Wouldn't these classes work better inheriting from each other?

Comment: The instance of test1 would be considered the root. I'm also assuming that "val" stores the minimum value calculated so far.

Comment: None of your classes represent a tree!

Comment: This sounds like a homework question...

Comment: txwikinger, these classes represent trees of bounded depth (test3 - depth 1, test2 - depth 2, test1 - depth 3)

Comment: I've simplified the question from a real-world situation. My actual problem stems from using Entity Framework over some related database tables. Each table stores a value column, and I need to find the minumum value for all (or a subset) of tables.

Comment: I tried to use LINQ, but ended up with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162362/nested-linq-min-crashes-visual-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a method in the top-level class to flatten the structure out into an IEnumerable.

```
public IEnumerable<int> FlattenVal()
{
    yield return this.val;
    foreach (var t2 in this.Tests)
    {
        yield return t2.val;
        foreach (var t3 in t2.Tests)
        {
            yield return t3.val;
            foreach (var t4 in t3.Tests)
            {
                yield return t4.val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you could call it like this:

```
var t = new Test1();

Console.WriteLine(t.FlattenVal().Min());
```

If you cant add the method directly to the class (non-partial, code generated, or in a library), then you could use an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FlattenVal(this Test1 t1)
{
    yield return t1.val;
    foreach (var t2 in t1.Tests)
    {
        yield return t2.val;
        foreach (var t3 in t2.Tests)
        {
            yield return t3.val;
            foreach (var t4 in t3.Tests)
            {
                yield return t4.val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-recursive (and non-tested) solution:

```
int minVal(test1 t1) {
   int min = t1.val;
   foreach (test2 t2 in t1.Tests) {
      min = Math.Min(min, t2.val);
      foreach (test3 t3 in t2.Tests) {
         min = Math.Min(min, t3.val);
         foreach (test4 t4 in t3.Tests) {
             min = Math.Min(min, t4.val);
         }
      }
   }
   return min;
}
```

Comment: How does this represent an algorithm searching a tree?

Comment: How does the structure in the original question represent a tree?

Answer (score 2):

I must admit that the question seems somewhat weird, but here is a solution that introduces two base classes, `TestBase` and `Test<T>` so the minimum finding algorithm can be kept in one place:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public abstract class TestBase {
  public int Val;
  public virtual int GetMin() {
    return Val;
  }
}
public abstract class Test<T> : TestBase where T : TestBase {
  public List<T> Tests;
  public override int GetMin() {
    return Math.Min(Val, Tests.Select(t => t.GetMin()).Min());
  }
}
public class Test1 : Test<Test2> {
}
public class Test2 : Test<Test3> {
}
public class Test3 : Test<Test4> {
}
public class Test4 : TestBase {
}
```

I changed the casing used for identifiers to something that made me feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and written up a complete console program that should work. Here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public interface ITest
    {
        int val {get; set; }
        List<ITest> Tests {get; set; }
    }
    public class Test1 : ITest
    {
        public int val { get; set; }
        public List<ITest> Tests {get; set; }
        public Test1()
        {
            Tests = new List<ITest>();
        }
    }
    public class Test2 : ITest
    {
        public int val { get; set; }
        public List<ITest> Tests {get; set; }
        public Test2()
        {
            Tests = new List<ITest>();
        }
    }
    public class Test3 : ITest
    {
        public int val { get; set; }
        public List<ITest> Tests {get; set; }
        public Test3()
        {
            Tests = new List<ITest>();
        }
    }
    public class Test4 : ITest
    {
        public int val { get; set; }
        public List<ITest> Tests {
            get { return new List<ITest>(); }
            set {} 
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static int GetMinVal(ITest initialTest, out ITest testWithMinVal)
        {
            int minVal = initialTest.val;
            testWithMinVal = initialTest;
            foreach (ITest t in initialTest.Tests)
            {
                if (t.val < minVal)
                {
                    minVal = GetMinVal(t, out testWithMinVal);
                }
            }
            return minVal;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            Test1 test = new Test1();
            test.val = r.Next(100);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Test2 test2 = new Test2();
                test2.val = r.Next(100);
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    Test3 test3 = new Test3();
                    test3.val = r.Next(100);
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    {
                        Test4 test4 = new Test4();
                        test4.val = r.Next(100);
                        test3.Tests.Add(test4);
                    }
                    test2.Tests.Add(test3);
                }
                test.Tests.Add(test2);
            }
            ITest testA;
            int minVal = GetMinVal(test, out testA);
            Console.WriteLine(minVal);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Provided that order doesn't matter, I *strongly* recommend storing your data in a more appropriate data structure than a List. Go go gadget heap!

```
interface ILeftistHeap<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Func<T, T, int> Comparer { get; }
    int Height { get; }
    T Item { get; }
    ILeftistHeap<T> Left { get; }
    ILeftistHeap<T> Right { get; }
    ILeftistHeap<T> Delete();
    ILeftistHeap<T> Add(T item);
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
}

sealed class LeftistHeap<T> : ILeftistHeap<T>
{
    private static IEnumerator<T> CreateEnumerator(ILeftistHeap<T> heap)
    {
        while (!heap.IsEmpty)
        {
            yield return heap.Item;
            heap = heap.Delete();
        }
    }

    private static ILeftistHeap<T> Balance(T item, Func<T, T, int> comparer, ILeftistHeap<T> a, ILeftistHeap<T> b)
    {
        if (a.Height >= b.Height) { return new LeftistHeap<T>(comparer, b.Height + 1, item, a, b);  }
        else { return new LeftistHeap<T>(comparer, a.Height + 1, item, b, a); }
    }

    public static ILeftistHeap<T> Merge(ILeftistHeap<T> x, ILeftistHeap<T> y)
    {
        if (x.IsEmpty) { return y; }
        else if (y.IsEmpty) { return x; }
        else
        {
            Func<T, T, int> comparer = x.Comparer;
            if (comparer(x.Item, y.Item) <= 0) { return Balance(x.Item, comparer, x.Left, Merge(x.Right, y)); }
            else { return Balance(y.Item, comparer, y.Left, Merge(x, y.Right)); }
        }
    }

    public static ILeftistHeap<T> Make(Func<T, T, int> comparer) { return EmptyHeap<T>.Make(comparer); }
    public static ILeftistHeap<T> Make(Func<T, T, int> comparer, T item)
    {
        EmptyHeap<T> empty = EmptyHeap<T>.Make(comparer);
        return new LeftistHeap<T>(comparer, 1, item, empty, empty);
    }

    public Func<T, T, int> Comparer { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public T Item { get; private set; }
    public ILeftistHeap<T> Left { get; private set; }
    public ILeftistHeap<T> Right { get; private set; }
    public ILeftistHeap<T> Add(T item) { return Merge(this, Make(this.Comparer).Add(item)); }
    public ILeftistHeap<T> Delete() { return Merge(this.Left, this.Right); }
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return false; } }

    protected LeftistHeap(Func<T, T, int> comparer, int height, T item, ILeftistHeap<T> left, ILeftistHeap<T> right)
    {
        this.Comparer = comparer;
        this.Height = height;
        this.Item = item;
        this.Left = left;
        this.Right = right;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return LeftistHeap<T>.CreateEnumerator(this); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return LeftistHeap<T>.CreateEnumerator(this); }
}

sealed class EmptyHeap<T> : ILeftistHeap<T>
{
    private static IEnumerator<T> CreateEnumerator() { yield break; }
    public static EmptyHeap<T> Make(Func<T, T, int> comparer) { return new EmptyHeap<T>(comparer); }
    private EmptyHeap(Func<T, T, int> comparer) { this.Comparer = comparer; }
    public Func<T, T, int> Comparer { get; protected set; }
    public T Item { get { throw new Exception("Empty heap"); } }
    public int Height { get { return 0; } }
    public ILeftistHeap<T> Left { get { throw new Exception("Empty heap"); } }
    public ILeftistHeap<T> Right { get { throw new Exception("Empty heap"); } }
    public ILeftistHeap<T> Add(T item) { return LeftistHeap<T>.Make(this.Comparer, item); }
    public ILeftistHeap<T> Delete() { throw new Exception("Empty Heap"); }
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return true; } }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return EmptyHeap<T>.CreateEnumerator(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return EmptyHeap<T>.CreateEnumerator(); }
}
```

Adding items to the heap is O(log n). Getting the min/max value is O(1).

Comment: doesn't that mean that you're shifting the cost to creating the list rather than looking through it? i suppose that has advantages...

Comment: @RCIX: I'm not sure if you're being serious or not, but heaps are the default choice when you need to find the min/max element in a collection. For what its worth, the O(n log n) time it takes to create the heap performs better than the O(n^3) loop-based lookup using lists.